# exception thrown with `az artifacts universal publish`

Tags: azure, universal-packages

[In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78168358/azure-devops-artifacts-how-to-deploy-tools-for-internal-usage/78168529#78168529), I was suggested to use Universal Packages as a way to publish internally to my team in Azure DevOps application.

I tried with a simple executable, but I'm getting a huge exception that makes little sense. I don't understand.
I'm trying to determine if it is my mistake or a bug, but in any case, I'm very surprised by the unintelligible error.

This is my command:

> az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/Myorg --feed MyFeed --name MyPackageName --version 0.0.1 --path mytool.exe --description TestDescription --scope project --project ProjectName

Once I run my command, it says '- Publishing ..' for a few seconds, and then this error:

> Failed to hash a page of files. Exception listed below...
> An exception was thrown: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.b__11(FileBlobDescriptor file)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<CreateNonSwallowingFunc>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.PaginateAndProcessFilesHelperAsync(String sourceDirectory, Boolean shouldPreserveSymbolicLink, Boolean shouldPreservePermissionValue, IEnumerable`1 pathsInDir, Action`1 hashCompleteCallback, HashType hashType, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<<PaginateAndProcessFiles>b__0>d.MoveNext() Encountered an unexpected error. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<PublishAsync>b__11(FileBlobDescriptor file) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<PaginateAndProcessFilesHelperAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.PaginateAndProcessFilesHelperAsync(String sourceDirectory, Boolean shouldPreserveSymbolicLink, Boolean shouldPreservePermissionValue, IEnumerable`1 pathsInDir, Action`1 hashCompleteCallback, HashType hashType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.ExceptionExtensions.ReThrow(Exception ex)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<CreateNonSwallowingFunc>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.PaginateAndProcessFiles(String sourceDirectory, HashType hashType, IEnumerable`1 pages, Boolean shouldPreserveSymbolicLink, Boolean shouldPreservePermissionValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 hashCompleteCallback) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.PublishAsync(String sourceDirectory, IReadOnlyCollection`1 fileInfoList, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 otherFiles, ArtifactPublishOptions artifactPublishOptions, String manifestFileOutputPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.UPackClientShared.UPackSharedClient.PushWithoutCheckingForDuplicatePackageAsync(String projectNameOrId, String feedNameOrId, String packageName, String packageVersion, String description, String sourceDirectory, Boolean honorIgnoreOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.UPackClientShared.UPackSharedClient.PushAsync(String projectNameOrId, String feedNameOrId, String packageName, String packageVersion, String description, String sourceDirectory, Boolean honorIgnoreOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackPublishCommand.cs:line 59 --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPack.UPackExceptionMapper.WithExceptionHandlingAsync(Func`1 act) in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackExceptionMapper.cs:line 39
> at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand.ExecuteAsync() in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackPublishCommand.cs:line 57
> at ArtifactTool.Commands.CommandBase.OnExecuteAsync() in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\CommandBase.cs:line 105
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 77
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 62
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 25
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.b__0() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 505
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 611
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 57
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 145
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](IConsole console, String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 130
> at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 112
> Process ['C:\Users\RobertoBasile\.azure\azuredevops\cli\tools\artifacttool\ArtifactTool_win10-x64_0.2.308\artifacttool', 'universal', 'publish', '--service', 'https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg', '--patvar', 'AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_ARTIFACTTOOL_PATVAR', '--feed', 'MyFeed', '--package-name', 'mytool', '--package-version', '0.0.1', '--path', 'mytool.exe', '--project', 'ProjectName', '--description', 'TestDescription'] with PID 40472 exited with return code 1

What do you think is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> *Error*: "Failed to hash a page of files. Exception listed below... An exception was thrown: Object reference not set to an instance of an object":

The above error indicates a problem while the hashing process of your file `mytool.exe` is happening before uploading the package to Azure Artifacts.

Check the package (.NET) version because if it is outdated then also this conflict arises.

Check Az CLI and artifact tool version and update if required.

`az upgrade`

Verify the file path you are providing is accurately given.

*Note*: Update the devops extension with CLI command`az extension update --name azure-devops` if needed for your environment to avoid conflicts.

*After checking all the above, I tried to execute the same command as you to publish the artifacts and was able to perform it successfully.*

```bash
az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/Jahnavime --project myproj --scope project --feed myfeed --name mypackage --version '1.0.0' --description mypack --path "/home/madugula/go/pkg/mod"
```

[image]

[image]

*Reference*: [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)

Comment: I ran both `az upgrade` and `az extension update --name azure-devops` and I got 'You already have the latest azure-cli version: 2.58.0' and 'Latest version of 'azure-devops' is already installed.' The app is developed in .NET 8.0

Comment: After upgrading everything, it worked for me. Are you still facing the issue? @ff8mania

Comment: as I said before, I have nothing to update

Comment: Can you verify the package files once whether they are accurately given. @ff8mania

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround (not really a solution, but it can unstuck who has the same problem why we try to find a way).
Instead of `mytool.exe`, I use `C:\fullpath\mytool.exe`, which works.

It doesn't make a lot of sense, but it works. Hope it can help someone